# how to get product id and sku in magento with SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, magento, magento-1.7

i'm trying to get the product id and the SKU of each product in magento with SQL, i fount that the table `catalog_product_entity` has all the SKUs but no product id.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

entity_id is product's unique id so if you call `$product->getId();` you actually get entity_id

The reason for that column name is that product is an EAV (Entity Attribute Value) model so product is an entity - standardized EAV entity identification column name but it can bring confusion...

And the query:

```
SELECT entity_id as product_id, sku FROM catalog_product_entity
```

Comment: yes, but i don't need entity_id, i want product_id for my function, where could that be ?

Comment: is product_id === entity_id ?

Comment: entity_id is product_id in case of catalog_product_entity table

Comment: Yes, the entity_id IS the product ID.

Comment: That query does not get you the SKU too

Comment: How to get url key also?

Answer (score 1):

The column 'entity_id' **is** the ID for the products. So the `catalog_product_entity` table does contain both items.